# How is it called percent with base one?

Tags: probability, analysis, statistics, notation, terminology

When we are referring to something that is a percentage (base 100). We talk in these terms:
*There is 30 **percent** of water*
*It has 15 **percent** of fats*

But, when we are just representing these values in **base one**. How are they called?
Something like **perone** or exist a fancy name?
I mean this:
*There is 0,3 **perone** of water*
*It has 0,15 **perone** of fats*

Comment: quantity..................

Comment: A possible word is *proportion*.

Comment: @Henry Isn't proportion technically a comparison of fractions?

Comment: @ryang Are you saying $0.15$ is not a (decimal) fraction?

Comment: @Henry Not at all. Just thinking about how you might use the word 'proportion' here.

Comment: See the (unfortunate) [Uno (proposed dimensionless unit)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parts-per_notation#Uno_(proposed_dimensionless_unit)). Maybe 0,15 parts-per-unit.

Answer (score 1):

As far I know, there is no such word, but let's think how would we name it if there was one.

1% - percent - "Per centum" (Latin) - in each hundred

1‰ - permille - "Per mīlle" (Latin) - in each thousand

1‱ - basis point, but also *permyriad*- "Per myriad" (Greek, but also Late Latin) - in each ten thousand

So if we want to continue this towards larger units, we probably should use the Latin language as well.

$\frac{1}{10}$ - "Per Decem" - perdecem

$\frac{1}{1}$ - "Per Ūnum" - perunum

But again, there are no such words in English, as far I know.